# Param is missing or the value is empty - update method ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am working on an app for rockhounds that will allow them to track the rocks they have found. I am trying to finish a method that will allow users to update rocks. The method itself works if you go to the '/edit' page where you enter a url, but when trying to reach that page via a link from the show page for the rock I get an error:
Param is missing or the value is empty: rock
Its coming from line 43 in my rocks controller, inside the method rock_params. The parameters for this request are:

`{"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"tiQQjQCMi6lbDPOxQ2X7fNTamWEZ3EAandGQ1Tv4NJKxieVIUnnWcKh3efd9F2LIRZWBYeC5M3RuEr0/FHQnww==", "id"=>"6"}`

Here is my controller code

````
   before_action :find_rock, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]    
   def index
      @rocks = Rock.all 
   end

   def show
       @rock = Rock.find_by(id: params[:id])
   end

   def new
       @rock = Rock.new
   end

   def create 
       @rock = Rock.new(rock_params)

       if @rock.save
           redirect_to @rock
       else
           render :new
       end
   end

   def update
      if @rock.update(rock_params)
       redirect_to @rock
      else
       render :edit
      end
   end

   def destroy
       @rock = Rock.find(params[:id])
       @rock.destroy

       redirect_to rocks_path
   end

   private
   def rock_params
       params.require(:rock).permit(:id, :nick_name, :category, :minerals, :outcrop)
   end

   def find_rock
       @rock = Rock.find(params[:id])
   end
end ```

Here is the view code for the show page:

`<h1> Rock: </h1>
<h2> Rock Name: <%= @rock.nick_name %></h2>
<h2> Rock Type: <%= @rock.category %></h2>
<h2> Major Minerals: <%= @rock.minerals %></h2>
<h2> Outcrop? : <%= @rock.outcrop %></h2>

<%= link_to "Edit this rock", edit_rock_path(@rock), method: :patch %>
<%= link_to "Delete this rock", rock_path(@rock), method: :delete %> `

and the edit page:

```<%= form_for :rock do |f| %>
   Name: <%= f.text_field :nick_name %><br>
   Category: <%= f.select :category, ['Igneous', 'Sedimentary', 'Metamorphic'] %><br>
   Major Minerals <%= f.text_area :minerals %><br>
   Outcrop or Boulder? <%= f.select :outcrop, ['Outcrop', 'Boulder'] %><br>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>  ```

and here are my routes:

```resources :rocks
 resources :users
 resources :locations

 post '/users/new', to:"users#create"
 get '/signup', to:"users#new", as: "signup"

 post '/rocks/new', to:"rocks#create"
 get '/rocks/:id/edit', to:"rocks#edit"
 patch '/rocks/:id/edit', to:"rocks#update"
 post '/rocks/:id/destroy', to:"rocks#destroy"
 root to: "rocks#index"



 get '/login', to: "auth#login", as: "login"
 post '/login', to: "auth#authenticate"

 get '/logout', to: "auth#logout"```

So the question is **How do I fix the empty param error that occurs when clicking the link to edit a rock from the show page for that rock?**
````

Comment: Can you show the link in your show.rb ?  It should be something like `<%= link_to 'Edit this rock', edit_rock_path(@rock) %>`

Comment: Ah, and I just noticed you didn't name your routes... `
`get '/rocks/:id/edit', to:"rocks#edit",  as: 'edit_rock'`

Comment: `resources :rocks` should have given you named routes.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I do have the link on the show page. It's below all the things in the h2 tags.

Comment: @toodles can you remove the method: :patch from the edit_rock_path link? Edit paths are GET routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@toodles from the rails documentation [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), edit paths are of the HTTP verb GET.

You need to change this line `<%= link_to "Edit this rock", edit_rock_path(@rock), method: :patch %>`, remove `method: :patch` which applies a PUT HTTP verb

It should look like this `<%= link_to "Edit this rock", edit_rock_path(@rock) %>` as rails applies the GET verb if the method is not specified.

You'll be able to see this when you inspect your link in a browser

Also, since you defined the `resource :rocks`, you don't need to redefine the other `rock` routes below it. You can see the generated routes with the `rails routes` command in your terminal.

You can also `add` an `edit` action to your controller, that returns `@rock`, which you use in the edit page. [This section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-articles) of the getting started with Rails article shows it clearly.

Comment: I tried this out, now I can click on the link and be taken to the edit form, but when i hit submit I get the error `No route matches [POST] "/rocks/7/edit"`.

Comment: figured it out, I needed to specify that the method would be PATCH in my edit form. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: That's awesome @toodles! Glad to help!